# mysql client exits with unsupported argunent during provisioning

Tags: mariadb, terraform, amazon-aurora

I have a TF script that deploys an ec2 instance with amazon linux and installs the mariadb x86_64 1:5.5.62-1.amzn2.0.1. I wish to automate the creation of databases and users on an aurora 5.7 RDS with only private access.

The issue is that, during the provisioner inline execution, every mysql comman I issue returns an error:

```
aws_instance.instance (remote-exec): mysql: unknown option '--print-defaults'
```

The same comman run from the instance via ssh works fine.

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
    ami                         = "ami-0c3fd0f5d33134a76" #data.aws_ami.ami.id
    availability_zone           = local.az
    ebs_optimized               = var.instance_config.ebs_optimized
    instance_type               = var.instance_config.type
    monitoring                  = var.instance_config.monitoring
    key_name                    = var.instance_config.key_name
    subnet_id                   = local.subnet_id
    vpc_security_group_ids      = local.security_groups
    associate_public_ip_address = var.instance_config.associate_public_ip_address
    source_dest_check           = var.instance_config.source_dest_check
    iam_instance_profile        = aws_iam_instance_profile.profile.name

    root_block_device {
        volume_type           = var.instance_config.volume_type
        volume_size           = var.instance_config.volume_size
        delete_on_termination = var.instance_config.delete_on_termination
    }

    connection {
        host     = self.public_ip
        type     = "ssh"
        user     = "ec2-user"
        private_key = file(var.instance_config.private_key_path)
    }

    provisioner "remote-exec" {
        inline = local.commands  ### mysql commands are here
    }

}
```

mysql commands are like

nmysql -h XXX.rds.amazonaws.com -u XXX -pXXX -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test;"

I tried inline execution, creating a script and then execute it, --no-defaults option for the client, created ~/.my.cnf  with the same issue.
I really would like to avoid logging in manually to create databases and opening the RDS to the public...

Update:
I have no --print-defaults in the script/commands. I also grepped the whole filesystem looking for some default setting in amazon linux... Also checked the env variables during the provisioner execution and after ssh connection but I found no differences

thanks

Comment: Your sample command does not include -print defaults option. Actually, it does not make sense to inlude that option in a script tha automtes anything.

Comment: that's why I'm asking here. I have no --print*defaults in the script/commands. I also grepped the whole filesystem looking for some default setting in amazon linux... Also checked the env variables during the provisioner execution and after ssh connection but I found no differences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a nodejs script that does the mysql database setup and that works just fine :)